# Best way to save internal datas?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

The thing is: when I started to learn developing for android, I thought I would store my internal datas in public static variables within a dedicated class, for this purpose only, so I could access them from any activity easily, and it was and still is pretty important, that there won't be any duplicate, and theese values are always unique, something like a Singleton model.  This is working awesomely, tho it is not the prettiest solution for sure. The problem starts when the user puts the application to the background via home button. It remains there for god knows how much time, maybe minutes, maybe days, or even more...then he reopens the application, and all theese static variables became null, since the system already destroyed them. Some of theese variables are simple Strings, but some are pretty complex, own classes.

The first question is, is there any global hook that I can rely on, where I can save theese datas, when the app goes to the background? So when the user pulls the app to the foreground again, I could just reinitialize theese variables from the saved state.

The second question is, what would be the best way to save theese complex datas? As far as I understand, for saving Strings SharedPreferences are just fine, but what about the more complex classes? Can I use SharedPreferences as well, or should I use something else?

For now this is all I can think of, thx for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad idea with the whole static variables in class. Ignoring the whole global variable debacle, they don't persist. You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or a database if you need to persist data.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question I believe what you are looking for is something similar to the onResume() method in the activity lifecycle.

For your question about storage, sqlLite is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

This [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) provides an explanation of all data storage options on Android. SharedPreferences are great for simple types, but it sounds like you would be better off using one or more [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) databases.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use Shared preferences and this is an easiest example for just that:

```
//Create a new class

public class PizzaApplication extends Application {

private static String sharedPreferences = "Pizza";
private static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate (){
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
}

public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getString(Context context, String pKey) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPref.getString(pKey, null);
}
}

//FROM ACTIVITY
//Save string

PizzaApplication.saveString(getApplicationContext(), "country", "test");

//Receive it 

String testString = PizzaApplication.getString(getApplicationContext(), "country"); //returns "test"
```